# What rights do landlords in Ontario have regarding prompt delivery of Preliminary Notice for Annual General Meeting

Tags: canada, real-estate, ontario, real-property, condominium

I live in Toronto, Ontario. Our condo's AGM is to be held on February 10, 2022 this year, and the deadline for nominating directors and submitting questions is Jan 10, 2022. However, although the Preliminary Notice is dated December 27, I did not receive it until Jan 11, 2022. I don't have any evidence that the letter was not delivered earlier, as I live in the building and it was dropped in my mailbox by the Management Office directly. Nevertheless, I am certain that it was only delivered today because I have the habit of checking my mailbox everyday. Besides I saw the same envelops lying around the mailboxes today.

I'm not sure what rights does a landlord have under the Condo Act with regard to this situation? And what are the legal steps should a landlord take to protect those rights? Should I send an email to the Management and ask for an explanation? Can I make a complaint to CONDOMINIUM MANAGEMENT REGULATORY AUTHORITY OF ONTARIO (CMRAO)?

Comment: You may want to try the cordial method first.  How about a communication that says "Hi, I had intended to nominate a candidate for the board but did not become aware of the Jan 10, 2022 deadline until I received the notice on Jan 11, 2022"?